# Modify Pagination URL on SHOPIFY using javascript

Tags: javascript, collections, shopify

The current pagination format is:

```
https://poptopia.us/collections/new?page=2
https://poptopia.us/collections/funko-pop?page=2
```

But I need the URL format to be:

```
https://poptopia.us/collections/new/2
https://poptopia.us/collections/funko-pop/2
```

Using Javascript I was able to modify the pagination URL like this:

```
`https://poptopia.us/collections/{{ collection.url }}/2/`
```

but it doesn't show/put the name of the current collection instead it shows: {{ collection.url }} how can I displayed the name of the collection there?

Here is the Javascript code i am implementing:

```
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var paginationLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a');
     var collectionUrl = '{{ collection.url }}';

     paginationLinks.forEach(function(link) {
     var pageUrl = link.getAttribute('href');
     var pageNumber = pageUrl.substring(pageUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

     link.setAttribute('href', collectionUrl + '/' + pageNumber + '/');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is from 8 months ago, but I came across it when looking for something else. Not sure if you still need an answer, but here it goes. You haven't mentioned where you're adding the code, but just in case, when outputting `{{ collection }}`, you will need to make sure you are in a `.liquid` file because Liquid is rendered serverside. It won't work if you add it in a `.js` file (but you can have a `.js.liquid` file). An easier way to do it would be to just add a script tag in the collection template, which would allow you to access your Liquid variables there.

In regards to `{{ collection.url }}`, I think you might be looking for the [collection handle](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/collection#collection-handle) so that you can output the collection's handle/slug.